# Vulkan where to do computations

Tags: vulkan, compute-shader

I am still a complete newbie at this so please treat me as someone who has 0 knowledge on this topic.

I'm currently making a vkCmdDraw call every frame with the vertexCount argument as 6 * numOfQuads, whilst binding a UBO that holds data for each quad, that will be used for computations inside the vertex shader.

Is it more efficient to do the computations outside of the shader (CPU), where I do all the computations prior to calling vkCmdDraw, or should I just stick to what I've currently got?

Comment: What computations are we talking about? The only "computation" you mentioned was "6 * numOfQuads", which is trivial.

Comment: @NicolBolas By computation, I mean computations using the data stored in the UBO. If I had variables like `xPos, yPos`, along with several other variables stored in the UBO used to transform those x and y position coordinates inside of the shader, would it be better to do these transformations inside the vertex shader or outside?

Comment: It all depends. Where do the quads come from? Where does the transformation come from? What operations did you use to get the data there, and how frequently is it updated? Performance is never as simple as "just do this thing". Also, why is this question tagged "compute shader"? You never ask about CSs.

Comment: @NicolBolas Its something I wanted to ask about. Are compute shaders something I could consider using for my particular case? If I was doing my transformations inside my vertex shader, should/could I move them to a separate (compute) shader?

Comment: A use case for compute shaders when... drawing *quads*? You're talking about one of the simplest possible things you can draw with a GPU, something that was already fast on pre-shader hardware.

Comment: So then I don't need to worry about all this right?

Comment: For 6 quads, the vertex shader performance is going to be insignificant. Don't worry about it.